# Is there a regular expression in Perl to find a file's extension?

Tags: perl

Is there a regular expression in Perl to find a file's extension? For example, if I have "`test.exe`", how would I get the "`.exe`"?

Comment: @Ether..I think its a great question. I have been into Perl on and off for more than a decade and there are times when I just want some quick reference.

Answer (score 47, accepted):

```
my $file = "test.exe";

# Match a dot, followed by any number of non-dots until the
# end of the line.
my ($ext) = $file =~ /(\.[^.]+)$/;

print "$ext\n";
```

Comment: This is perfect.  Is there a regex command to separate the two in one shot?   i.e.'happy.jpg' and you would be left with two variable, one equal to 'happy' and one '.jpeg

Comment: When the filename doesn't have an extension, you will get a `Use of uninitialized value $ext` error on the print statement.

Answer (score 14):

use [`File::Basename`](https://perldoc.perl.org/File/Basename.html)

```
  use File::Basename;
  ($name,$path,$suffix) = fileparse("test.exe.bat",qr"\..[^.]*$");
  print $suffix;
```

Comment: I've never thought that File::Basename was any good for this job considering that you have to supply the pattern that you could have used with the match operator to get the same thing done.

Comment: if its just to get extension, a normal regex would suffice. But File::Basename parses the rest of the path as well. If OP needs to get them besides extension need, File::Basename comes in handy.

Comment: Warning: I had files which users named as `filename..doc` and the regep for suffix above will return `..doc` as the extension.  Prefer the one in @toolic reply (or the Perl Docs for File:Basename) if going in this direction.

Answer (score 4):

```
\.[^\.]*$
```

This would give you everything after the last dot (including the dot itself) until the end of the string.

Answer (score 4):

Here it is a regex to match pattern n-level extension file (e.g. *.tar.gz* or *.tar.bz2*).

```
((\.[^.\s]+)+)$
```

Example:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

my $file1 = "filename.tar.gz.bak";
my ($ext1) = $file1 =~ /((\.[^.\s]+)+)$/;

my $file2 = "filename.exe";
my ($ext2) = $file2 =~ /((\.[^.\s]+)+)$/;

my $file3 = "filename. exe";
my ($ext3) = $file3 =~ /((\.[^.\s]+)+)$/;

my $file4 = "filename.............doc";
my ($ext4) = $file4 =~ /((\.[^.\s]+)+)$/;

print "1) $ext1\n"; # prints "1) .tar.gz.bak"
print "2) $ext2\n"; # prints "2) .exe"
print "3) $ext3\n"; # prints "3) "
print "4) $ext4\n"; # prints "4) .doc"
```

Answer (score 3):

You could use [File::Basename](http://perldoc.perl.org/File/Basename.html) to extract an arbitrary file extension:

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use File::Basename;
my $ext = (fileparse("/foo/bar/baz.exe", qr/\.[^.]*/))[2];
print "$ext";
```