# Correct stream for interactive in perl

Tags: perl, bash, stdout, out

My perl script needs to ask the user for a password to download some files:

```
print "Your password please: \n";
ReadMode('noecho');
$password = ReadLine(0);
$password =~ s/\n//;
ReadMode(0);

system("wget --user=user --password=\"$password\" http://some.server/data.xml");
do_something();
```

If I call the script with `$> ./script.pl` everything works fine. But if I want to pipe the output to a file with `$> ./script.pl > text.txt`, the password question is piped to the file, too, and the ReadLine does not work any longer.

What is the right way to do this?

Comment: The easiest solution is probably to add `-O text.txt` to your `wget` command.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Print the prompt to `STDERR`:

```
print STDERR "Your password please: ";
```

Answer (score 0):

The security gain from reading the password directly off the keyboard is nullified by shelling out to `wget`, in whose environment the password is plainly visible for every user on the system. If security does not matter, you can rewrite your program to [take command-line parameters](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10957826/46395) for the user/password.